# "Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind" when trying to debug in Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP

Tags: java, actionscript-3, debugging, sockets, flash-builder

Im trying to debug an app, not server related yet, with the new version of the FB, the one that comes with Zend in it.

Thing is, everytime I try to debug, the message error is the same:

"Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind"

Do any of you have an idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check your ports

JVM_Bind means the server socket could not connect to that port as its already being used by another server socket

netstat (with -b param ) should tell you the ports being used and the exe that started listening on it

make sure it is not being used

Comment: How do I know what port is the one I need to check out?

Comment: Everything is hard coded just run netstat to get the port in use and make sure you don't use one of them. Generally I use 21212 and never had an issue with it before. Sometimes I also use 12345.

Comment: Didnt work, seted the port to 12345, I double checked that Im not using that port, and same error. /Uninstalling Flash 4.5 for PHP :)

Comment: Damn it, even uninstalling FB and installing the normal version gives me the same error, that zend thingy screwed something up somewhere... Ill check the firewall... sigh.

Comment: It seems to me the problem is on the java side not being able to bind the socket. Not Fb nor zend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close other programs or services that could open ports.
2. Check mm.cfg file content c:\Users{Username}\mm.cfg for Win7. There could be strange settings for profiler. Actually you can remove this file to reset debug setting (with backup!).

I afraid that zend debugger could bind to the same port.